# clarify behaviour: collections.defaultdict vs dict.setdefault

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, defaultdict

`dict` provides `.setdefault()`, which will allow you to assign values, of any type, to missing keys on the fly:

```
>>> d = dict()
>>> d.setdefault('missing_key', [])
[]
>>> d
{'missing_key': []}
```

Whereas, if you use `defaultdict` to accomplish the same task, then the default value is generated on demand whenever you try to access or modify a missing key:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> d['missing_key']
[]
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'missing_key': []})
```

However, the following piece of code implemented with `defaultdict` raises a `KeyError` instead of creating the item with default value, `{}`:

```
trie = collections.defaultdict(dict)
for word in words:
    t = trie
    for c in word:
        t = t[c]
    t["*"] = word
```

Using `.setdefault()` works ok:

```
trie = {}
for word in words:
    t = trie
    for c in word:
        t = t.setdefault(c, {})
    t["*"] = word
```

checking before access, works ok too:

```
trie = {}
for word in words:
    t = trie
    for c in word:
        if c not in t:
           t[c] = {}
        t = t[c]
    t["*"] = word
```

What am I missing when using `collections.defaultdict()`?

**NB**
I am trying to build a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) structure out of a list of words. For example:

```
words = ["oath", "pea", "eat", "rain"]
trie = {'o': {'a': {'t': {'h': {'*': 'oath'}}}}, 'p': {'e': {'a': {'*': 'pea'}}}, 'e': {'a': {'t': {'*': 'eat'}}}, 'r': {'a': {'i': {'n': {'*': 'rain'}}}}}
```

Comment: In my first example, if word = "oath", it fails at `a`...it doesn't get to `t["*"]`. Could you elaborate how the, `t = t[c]`, assignment changes it to a regular `dict`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first example, when you do t = t[c], t becomes a regular empty `dict` (because that's what you tell the `defaultdict` to generate in the definition of `trie`).

Let's run through the loop with your example word `"oath"`:

```py
1) t = trie, word = "oath"
2) c = "o"
3) t = t[c]
  3.1) evaluation of t[c] # "o" is not in trie, so trie generates an empty dict at key "o" and returns it to you
  3.2) assignment to t -> t is now the empty dict. If you were to run (t is trie["o"]), it would evaluate to True after this line
4) c = "a"
5) t = t[c]
  5.1) Evaluation of t[c] -> "a" is not in the dict t. This is a regular dict, raise KeyError.
```

Unfortunately, I can't think of a way to use `defaultdict` here ([but Marius could, see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63131539/3214872)), because of the arbitrary nesting of a Trie. You'd need to define the trie as a defaultdict that, in case of missing key, generates a default dict *that itself generates a default dict in case of missing key*, recursively until maximum depth (which, in principle, is unknown).

IMO, the best way to implement this is with the `setdefault` as you did in your second example.

Answer (score 2):

[GPhilo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63131360/1433901) is perfectly fine and, indeed, I also believe that `setdefault` is the proper way of doing it.

However, if one prefers to use the `defaultdict`, it can be easily achieved like this:

```py
def ddnestedconst(): 
    """collections.defaultdict nested-ish constructor."""
    return collections.defaultdict(ddnestedconst) 

# ...

trie = collections.defaultdict(ddnestedconst)
# or, being the same:
#trie = ddnestedconst()

for word in words:
    t = trie
    for c in word:
        t = t[c]
    t["*"] = word
```

May feel a little bit strange at first, but I find it perfectly readable and semantically accurate.

Reached that point, you may also prefer to create a new class altogether, inspired by `defaultdict`, but including all the semantics and specific behaviour that you expect from it.

Comment: I was also thinking of something towards this direction, though I wasn't sure it was feasible. Thanks for adding to my answer (and showing me how to implement something new)!